# ruby installed with rbenv not found when running script called from init.d

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, rbenv

I'm using chef to deploy to a test machine.  The first part of the recipe is to install rbenv.

The next part is to clone the [newrelic_sidekiq_agent git repo](https://github.com/secondimpression/newrelic_sidekiq_agent) under `/web/newrelic_sidekiq_agent`.

The next part is to create an init.d script from the following template.

```
APP_PATH=/web/newrelic_sidekiq_agent

. /etc/rc.d/init.d/functions

start() {
  cd $APP_PATH && ./newrelic_sidekiq_agent.daemon start
}

stop() {
  cd $APP_PATH && ./newrelic_sidekiq_agent.daemon stop
}

status() {
  cd $APP_PATH && ./newrelic_sidekiq_agent.daemon status
}

case "$1" in
  start)
    start
    ;;
  stop)
    stop
    ;;
  restart)
    $0 stop
    $0 start
    ;;
  status)
    status
    ;;
  *)
    echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop|status|restart}"
    exit 1
    ;;
esac
```

The content of `newrelic_sidekiq_agent.daemon` is

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'rubygems'
require 'daemons'
require 'bundler/setup'

Daemons.run(File.dirname(Pathname.new(__FILE__).realpath) + '/newrelic_sidekiq_agent')
```

The chef recipe fails because it can't find the ruby bin.  The error I get is

```
Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed
------------------------------------
Expected process to exit with [0], but received '127'
---- Begin output of /sbin/service newrelic_sidekiq_agent start ----
STDOUT:
STDERR: /usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
---- End output of /sbin/service newrelic_sidekiq_agent start ----
```

Logging in to the server, I set the global ruby version and then ran the following.

```
>> rbenv global
2.1.6

>> which ruby
/opt/rbenv/shims/ruby

>> /sbin/service newrelic_sidekiq_agent status
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory

>> ./newrelic_sidekiq_agent.daemon status
newrelic_sidekiq_agent: running [pid 25208]
```

Changing the call to ruby to use absolute path works with the init.d script.

```
#!/usr/bin/env /opt/rbenv/shims/ruby
```

Is there a way to make it work so I don't have to use absolute path?

Comment: What chef cookbook did you use to install rbenv? If you used one of the community ones, they have methods for marking the ruby as 'global' which will make it the default. Perhaps you've omitted that? Knowing how you installed rbenv (what cookbook, what recipe, what attributes) would be hugely helpful to troubleshooting why that install didn't work the way you expected.

Comment: i've manually set a global ruby version in the machine (as you can see from the result of rbenv global above).